# More than one publisher & transport installed on the same server

Tags: publishing, content-manager

Is it a supported scenario (or even possible) to have more than one Publisher & Transport Service installed & running on the same server?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use case to have more than one publisher and transport service in the same server. Performance, Testing of scaling & configuration?

Comment: The only use case I can think of where this would make sense is for Publisher restrictions - mapping certain Publications or Targets to certain Publishers - which you cannot do in a single machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, this won't work. The only way to scale these services is to add more [render](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-863D3D2F-380D-48B3-A4B5-E195FDE7A6A8) and [transport](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-D57EB55B-DC10-42E9-8F8C-69F87E018A6C) threads.